# SEO and Javascript Data Load

Tags: rest, seo, web-crawler

These days modern sites are becoming more and more service oriented like facebook/gmail.

A main page is loaded and then with ajax requests it calls all sorts of data and adds them on the site. This is also something that is promoted on ASP.NET MVC4 with the Web API.

So now lets say we want to create a product category page for a eshop. It has come to my understanding that the way to go with this implementation is to create a nice layout and create a Web API that will retrieve all data on request.

So we'll have a url like

```
/api/Products
```

that will retun a json with all of our products and then we can build up with this api by adding filters/paging maybe (/api/Products?sort-by=name) or anything else that will return the filtered json and we can pass with ajax requests back and forth offering the user an excellent experience.

My question with this now is what happens with SEO.

So a few years ago without onepage ajax/service oriented sites we would have

```
http://website.com/apples/
http://website.com/apples/2/
```

that would load the list of the apples with pagination.

Now the site would be

```
http://website.com/apples/
```

however it wouldn't load the apples instantly but load a blank page and call the service

```
/api/apples
```

that would return a json and then load the data on the site.

I read this article at Google https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot which didn't convince me. I really don't want to load the service behind and then string replace.

It is possible to have the

```
http://website.com/apples/
```

that would call the service

```
/api/apples
```

and load the data and be at the same time Google friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Either you can use HTML5 pushState to update the URL, but then you also will need to create a version of your site that works without JavaScript turned on.

Another option is to use [Googles AJAX Crawling specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). I don't know which search providers that currently supports it, but should be a good way to at least get into Googles search results.